# Use two getJSON calls separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, npr-api

I'm trying to use two getJSON calls for two separate (but nearly identical) purposes. I'm a novice, but I was able to cobble together the following code:

```js
$(function() {

 var call1, call2;
 jQuery.when(
  jQuery.getJSON('https://api.composer.nprstations.org/v1/widget/517ed638e1c8d825471462ff/tracks?format=json&limit=16', function(data) {
   call1 = data;
  }),
  jQuery.getJSON('https://api.composer.nprstations.org/v1/widget/51929bfde1c8886d5ccfb1d9/tracks?format=json&limit=11', function(data) {
   call2 = data;
  })
 ).then(function() {  
  if (call1.onNow.song) {
   
   var output1="<ul>";
   
   for (var i in call1.tracklist.results) {
    
    var item1 = call1.tracklist.results[i];
    
    if (item1.song.artistName && item1.song.trackName) {
     output1 += "<li>" + item1.song.trackName + "</li>";
    }
   };
   
   output1 += '</ul>';   
   document.getElementById("call1-playlist").innerHTML=output1;
  };
  
  if (call2.onNow.song) {
   
   var output2="<ul id='playlist'>";
   
   for (var i in call2.tracklist.results) {
    
    var item2 = call2.tracklist.results[i];
    
    if (item2.song.artistName && item2.song.trackName) {
     output2 += "<li>" + item2.song.trackName + "</li>";
    }
   };
   
   output2 += '</ul>';   
   document.getElementById("call2-playlist").innerHTML=output2;
  }; 
 });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="call1-playlist">Placeholder</div>
<div id="call2-playlist">Placeholder</div>
```

When I make the getJSON calls, it pulls the data from both sources. But I can't get both `if (call1.onNow.song) ...` and `if (call2.onNow.song) ...` to both work at the same time. They each work if only one is present, but not when they're both in the code.

I'm assuming it's something relatively simple that I'm missing. Again, I'm a novice, so I'm not sure where to look in the code for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the API doesn't return a `song` property in the second call. However, it does appear to return a `program` property which may be suitable. I'm not really familiar with the NPR API, but it makes sense that two songs won't be playing at once.

Simply change this:

```
if (call2.onNow.song)
```

To this:

```
if (call2.onNow.program)
```

Run the snippet below to see if it suits your needs.

```js
$(function() {

 var call1, call2;
 jQuery.when(
  jQuery.getJSON('https://api.composer.nprstations.org/v1/widget/517ed638e1c8d825471462ff/tracks?format=json&limit=16', function(data) {
   call1 = data;
  }),
  jQuery.getJSON('https://api.composer.nprstations.org/v1/widget/51929bfde1c8886d5ccfb1d9/tracks?format=json&limit=11', function(data) {
   call2 = data;
  })
 ).then(function() {  
  if (call1.onNow.song) {
   
   var output1="<ul>";
   
   for (var i in call1.tracklist.results) {
    
    var item1 = call1.tracklist.results[i];
    
    if (item1.song.artistName && item1.song.trackName) {
     output1 += "<li>" + item1.song.trackName + "</li>";
    }
   };
   
   output1 += '</ul>';   
   document.getElementById("call1-playlist").innerHTML=output1;
  };
  
  if (call2.onNow.program) {
   var output2="<ul id='playlist'>";
   
   for (var i in call2.tracklist.results) {
    
    var item2 = call2.tracklist.results[i];
    
    if (item2.song.artistName && item2.song.trackName) {
     output2 += "<li>" + item2.song.trackName + "</li>";
    }
   };
   
   output2 += '</ul>';   
   document.getElementById("call2-playlist").innerHTML=output2;
  }; 
 });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="call1-playlist">Placeholder</div>
<div id="call2-playlist">Placeholder</div>
```

Comment: I think I realize where I initially hit the snag. I was repurposing old code I had written for an almost-but-not-quite identical purpose where `onNow.song` is relevant (it does return data if there is a song currently listed as "now playing" in a playlist; if there isn't, it returns no data...like if you run the script now, only the second call works because there's no "now playing" song in either playlist). I was looking at every piece of the code except that.

Answer (score 0):

a neater way to achieve the above:

```
jQuery.getJSON('https://api.composer.nprstations.org/v1/widget/517ed638e1c8d825471462ff/tracks?format=json&limit=16', function(data) {
    callback(data, 'call1-playlist');
});

jQuery.getJSON('https://api.composer.nprstations.org/v1/widget/51929bfde1c8886d5ccfb1d9/tracks?format=json&limit=11', function(data) {
    callback(data, 'call2-playlist');
});

function callback(data, id) {
    if (data.onNow.song) {
        var $ul = $('<ul/>');

        $.each(data.tracklist.results, function () {
            if (this.song.artistName && this.song.trackName) {
                $ul.append($('<li>' + this.song.trackname + '</li>');
            }
        });

        $('#' + id).html($ul);
    }
}
```

Comment: assuming that $ is defined globally